# bool function problem - always returns true?

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

static bool isanagram(string a, string b);

int main(void)
{
    int i,n,j,s;
    cin >> n;
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if(!isanagram(a,b)) cout << "False" << endl;
    else cout << "True" << endl;
    return 0;


}

static bool isanagram(string a, string b)
{
    int i, j, size, s=0;
    size = a.size();
    bool k;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        k=false;
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == b[j]) { k = true; break; }
        }
        if(k==true) s+=1;
    }
    cout << a[2] << b[2] << endl;
    if(s == size) return true;
    else return false;

}
```

I don't know where exactly is the problem so i just pasted the whole code.

It should be a simple program capable for finding if two strings are anagrams, but it's not working and i don't know why. I used pointers in the program so thought the might be the problem and removed them, i removed other things additionally but still it's not working. If you can give it a look-see and tell me some idea where i might've gone wrong with my code ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: People might answer if you accepted more answers than you have so far.

Comment: btw, your code may crash if the the second string is shorter than the first one.

Comment: It's the figure which in your case is 0%, meaning you didn't accept any of the answers you've had to all your previous questions.

Comment: @ggg: This is your 9th question. You have not accepted any of the answers given to the other 8.

Comment: the string are supposed to be equal in size.

Comment: It also will not return the true answer if the first string contains two of the same character but the second string contains only one of that character.

Comment: You should pass std::string by const reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885785/passing-c-strings-by-value-or-by-reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: don't declare the method `static`. It's a confusing keyword at the best of times given all the roles it can fulfill... so reserve for times when you really have to (method or attribute of a class that is not tied to any instance for example).

Regarding the algorithm: you're nearly there, but presence only is not sufficient, you need to take the number of characters in account too.

Let's do it simply:

```
bool anagram(std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs)
{
  if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) return false; // does not cost much...

  std::vector<int> count(256, 0); // count of characters
  for (size_t i = 0, max = lhs.size(); i != max; ++i)
  {
    ++count[lhs[i]];
    --count[rhs[i]];
  }

  for (size_t i = 0, max = count.size(); i != max; ++i)
    if (count[i] != 0) return false;

  return true;
} // anagram
```

Let's see it at work: `anagram("abc","cab")`

1. Initialization: `count = [0, 0, ...., 0]`
2. First loop `i == 0` > `['a': 1, 'c': -1]`
3. First loop `i == 1` > `['a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': -1]`
4. First loop `i == 2` > `['a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0 ]`

And the second loop will pass without any problem.

Variants include maintaining 2 counts arrays (one for each strings) and then comparing them. It's slightly less efficient... does not really matter though.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3) std::cout << "Usage: Program Word1 Word2" << std::endl;
  else std::cout << argv[1] << " and " << argv[2] << " are "
                 << (anagram(argv[1], argv[2]) ? "" : "not ")
                 << "anagrams" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not always return true:

Here's my input:

```
0
sdf 
fda
```

Here's output I got:

```
fa 
False
```

Regarding your task: if performance is not an issue for you task, just sort 2 strings (using std::sort) and compare results.

Regarding your style:

- use string::length() instead of size() -- it's more idiomatic
- instead of `if(s == size) return true; else return false;` consider `return s == size`
- pass your strings by const reference, not by value
- consider declaring variables as close to point of their usage as possible (but not closely) and initialize them when declaring (i, j, k, size all fit this hint)

Comment: Why is `string::length` more idiomatic (despite being less generic)?

Answer (score 3):

The logic for your isanagram function is fatally flawed - it will never work correctly, even if you manage to fix the bugs in it.

You need to make sure that you have a correct algorithm before you start coding. One simple algorithm might be:

- sort a
- sort b
- isanagram = (a == b)

Answer (score 2):

There are essentially two ways of checking for anagrams:

1. Sort both strings and see if they match. If they are anagrams, they will both have the same letters and a sort would order them into the same sequence.
2. Count the frequency of each `char` in each string. If they are anagrams, the frequency counts for each `char` will be the same for both strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine but it has a small flaw. You ensuring that every char from string a is present in string. So if a = "aab" and b = "abc", your approach will flag them as anagram. You also need to take the count of char in account.

The definition of [anagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) is:

> An anagram is a type of word play, the result of rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase, using all the original letters **exactly once**;

Easiest way as many have suggested is to ensure that the strings are of the same length . If they are, sort the two string and check for equality.

If you want to patch your approach, you can make the char in string b NULL after it has been matched with a char in string a.

Something like:

```
if(a[i] == b[j]) { b[j] = 0; k = true; break; }
```

in place of your:

```
if(a[i] == b[j]) { k = true; break; }
```

This way once a char of b has been matched it cannot participate again.

Comment: If two strings are the same before sorting, are they anagrams?  The definition you cited says a *new word or phrase*, implying that the strings must be different before sorting.  Also, spaces should probably be removed, but this depends on the requirements of the homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your code.  Basically the algorithm is wrong.  It will match characters within a.size().  It takes no account for duplicates (in either a or b).

Essentially, you should sort the strings and then compare for equality.

If you can't sort, at least remove the b characters from the comparison, eliminate the k variable.