# Class inheritance error: Private member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, parent, private

I've got one base class/parent class: Person

And two subclasses/child classes: Player, Coach

This is what the header for the base class Person looks like:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string name);
        Person();
        virtual ~Person();
        string getName();
        void setName(string name);
        virtual void printSpec() const = 0;

    private:
        string name;
};
```

I tried to compile and run, it started complaining about this:

```
include\Person.h||In constructor 'Coach::Coach(std::string, std::string)':|
include\Person.h|19|error: 'std::string Person::name' is private|
\src\Coach.cpp|5|error: within this context|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

And pointed to this:

```
private:
    string name;
```

In the context of one out of two constructors for the child class "Coach":

```
Coach::Coach(string name, string responsibility): Person(name){
    this->name = name;
    this->responsibility = responsibility;
}
```

However, it doesn't make the same complaint about that very same line in the constructor of the "Player"-class, only complains about "string name being a private member" in the constructor of the "Coach"-class.

I looked up some solutions for other people, tried protected instead of private, tried changing the names of the variables, but to no use.

What gives?

Comment: If you are already calling Person(name) in the Coach constructor, why do you need to set this->name at all? I assume Person::Person takes care of that?

In any case, protected scope should work.

Comment: Get a [decent book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). `Player::name` is private. if you want derived classes to have member-level access (and there is no reason to in this case, but thats another matter) it needs to be *protected* or *public* or *friend*-ed (the latter highly unusual for derived classes).

Comment: How do you declare the Coach class? (Don't forget to use the public word in there too)

Comment: I've got it working now with protected, thanks. 
There's some example code that I've got, and it has private members and two subclasses who use the member without a hitch. Or I must've missed some trick in it to get it all to work, or perhaps it was all precompiled. Anyhow, problem solved now.

Comment: **Don't** make it protected. The constructor for `Person` will initialize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `private` member cannot be accessed by derived class.

The solution could be to use the *member-initialization-list* to do that :

```
Coach::Coach(string name, string responsibility): Person(name){
    //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                     Initialize the name through the base class constructor
    this->responsibility = responsibility;
}
```

Because `Person` is the *base-class* and have a constructor that takes a name, you can do it that way. You don't need to access the `name` member from the derived class.

---

Another solution could be to set this member `protected` (**the first solution is still better**).

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string name);
        Person();
        virtual ~Person();
        string getName();
        void setName(string name);
        virtual void printSpec() const = 0;

    protected:
//  ^^^^^^^^^
        string name;
};
```

You can take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/), the inheritance part talk about access-type.

---

Not to answer the question but for some good practice, I would suggest you to pass your `string` parameter as `const` reference. It is a [better practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582797/why-pass-by-const-reference-instead-of-by-value) :

```
Coach::Coach(const string& name, const string& responsibility): Person(name){
    //       ^^^^^       ^       ^^^^^       ^
    this->responsibility = responsibility;
}
```

Comment: `Coach` **is** derived from `Person`, so the constructor is the right approach. Changing `name` to `protected` is **wrong**. The constructor can initialize the member, and the `setName` member function can be used to set it later if needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, I edited my post to make it more appropriate. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is private in the base class, so you can't access it from a derived class.

Assuming that Coach derives publically from Person you could make the member variable protected, but fortunately the `Person` constructor takes a name, so you don't need to access it from the derived classes directly. You can use the initialiser list as you are doing and therefore don't need to set it twice

```
Coach::Coach(string name, string responsibility)
                   : Person(name){
                 //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 // Sends name to Person's constructor
    this->responsibility = responsibility;
}
```

Comment: `Coach` does not need to derive **publicly**; as long as `Person` is a base class, it can be initialized in the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

Change "private" to "protected"   private means no other part of the system, including derived classes, can access the member.

Comment: **Don't** change it to protected. The constructor for `Person` initializes `name`, and the `setName` member function changes it if needed. There is no reason to use `protected` here.

Comment: Agreed.  I was just addressing "why does the compiler generate an error".  Using an accessor method is better (in this case) than protected.